# Retrieving *.ascx control value in javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#

My *.ascx control is a combo box, nothing more, it has a few items as such

**MyDropDown.ascx**

```
<select id="Properties" name="properties">
    <option value="Name">Name</option>
    <option value="Age">Age</option>
    <option value="Phone">Phone</option>
</select>
```

**MyDropDown.ascx.cs**

```
//inside the class
public string SelectedValue
{
   get { return this.SelectedValue; }
   set { this.SelectedValue = value; }
}
```

**MyWebPage.aspx**

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="PropertyList" TagName="propertySelector" Src="~/Views/Shared/MyDropDown.ascx" %>

...
<PropertyList:propertySelector runat="server" ID="PropertySelect"/>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    function BtnClick()
    {
       var selectedValue = $('.PropertySelect').selectedValue;
       ...
    }
```

how do I access the selected value in the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, making a C# property isn't going to expose anything to the client.

Your issue is that you need a way to select the `select` element from the html instead of trying to select your user control. The easiest way to accomplish what you want is by keeping your code the way it is and adding `class='propertySelect'` to your select (because you're trying to select based on a css class. Your code is confused about whether you should be selecting by ID or by class). Otherwise you need to start thinking of ways to define a dynamic id for the `select` and write a selector for it.

Comment: ok so in my *.ascx page, include the class but then how do i access it? just like was doing before in the *.aspx?? also, it's not a CSS class

Comment: I was saying to use a CSS class as the "hook" for your jQuery selector. I'm not telling you to put a C# class in your user control. The C# property you're writing cannot be seen by jQuery. You need to have jQuery be able to find your HTML select, so you need to either define an ID for it, or you need to put a CSS class on it and make your jQuery selector reflect that. Of note: Setting the id of your user control does nothing. By default, a user control renders no HTML. Also, `$(".PropertySelect")` is telling jQuery to look for a CSS class named "PropertySelect"--to select by id use #

Comment: Javascript can only see the HTML that is output by your user control. You have to make the HTML select inside the user control known to jQuery.

Comment: My select in both ASPX and ASCX have ID values set as above... I've switched to using the # by $("#propertySelector") AND also tried $("#PropertySelect") but I'm still not able to do what I need

Comment: Dude. You can't select your user control using Javascript. I already said that. I also said you have to tell jQuery to select your select. If your select has an ID of "Properties" then you have to tell jQuery to look for "Properties". However, if you do select by id, what happens when you have 2 instances of your user control? You'll have 2 selects with the same id. Like I recommended before, use a CSS class on your select and save yourself the headache.

Comment: bro, I'm not visualizing what ur saying.. can you just post some code